# UTM on MacOS host, Ubuntu guest: how to network between host and guest?

Tags: network, virtualization

I have UTM 3.1.5 running on a new Mac Mini (M1), with an Ubuntu guest. By using networking mode "Emulate VLAN", I can get out through my host via the virtual adapter, and out to the Internet.

However, what I'd like to be able to do is all of that, plus be able to get from the guest to my home network where the host lives, and also from the host into the guest. Does that mean I have to set up a "bridged" networking setup? I tried that for a while with no success; I'd make an attempt, but then starting qemu would fail because something (UTM I guess) was constructing an invalid argument list.

Is there a way that I can make the guest OS look like another direct client of the same ordinary network that my other computers, and phones, and everything are on? (Maybe that's what "bridged" means.) I've tried to find documentation but it's sparse. I've used other VMs for many many years, but I haven't had to actually set this stuff up in a long time so I've forgotten everything.

Comment: I think I got it; I had been trying to configure too much stuff for the bridged network setup. If I give it nothing but the *host* adapter name, then it seems to just work in both directions. I wish I had those two hours back however. (I'll add an answer but I'll wait to see if somebody can provide a more well-informed one.)

Comment: Hi  @Pointy. I still do not get how to find the default ip address of the guest and how to find the default ip address of the host or their corresponding hostnames

Comment: @GeorgePligoropoulos unfortunately I stopped using UTM only a few days after posting this question, so I really don't remember exactly how I did it. I do sympathize with you, because what documentation there is assumes that the reader knows a lot about networking and network terminology.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming in 1y later, working on a Mac M1 V 4.3.5 (87), with a Windows 11 Guest System and a Shared Network Setup.

If you are in the guest and find do and search the gateway that Guest is using to connect to the internet, that should be the IP of the host, from the guest pov.

In Windows, open the command (CMD) and then type: `ipconfig`. You should get something similar like:

`Standardgateway ..... 192.168.XX.XX`